# do i need to verify my admob account as i'm already using verified adsense accout?

Tags: admob, adsense

Can I use my verified AdSense account for my AdMob? I have a verified AdSense account, but now I need an AdMob account. Should I verify my AdMob account again? Or is it already verified because of my verified AdSense account?

Answer (score 0):

No, You have to only link your verified Adsense account while creating Admob account. You will receive the payments through your Adsense account.